# Ejecutar código al hacer clic en fila de tabla

Tags: javascript

Buenas, me gustaría poder ejecutar el código que pongo mas abajo al hacer clic en una imagen que tengo en una fila de la tabla, algo aparentemente facil pero no consigo que salga.
Os dejo la función donde pinto la tabla .

```
function tareas(id) { //Funcion a l que le paso el id de la historia y me pinta la tabla con las tareas

 var parametros = {
        //"idHis":datos.id, 
        "idHis":id,
        "apiKey":"PlnDir"
    };


    $.ajax ({
            async:false,
            data: parametros,
            "url": "his_tarea.php", //web a la que llamo y hace el trabajo.
            type: "POST",


        success: function(data){
        objJson=JSON.parse(data);
        }   
    });


    var tablaTarea = '<table  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                        '<thead>'+
                            '<tr>'+
                                  '<td>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +'<img src="img/flecha.png" width="15" height="15"/>'+ '</td>' + '<td>Id:</td>'+   '<td>Tarea:</td>'+  '<td>Descripción:</td>'+  '<td>Colaborador:</td>'+
                            '</tr>'
                        +'</thead>'+'<tbody>';




    for(var i = 0; i < objJson.length; i++){
        tablaTarea += '<tr>'+
                               '<td>'+ '<img src="img/flecha.png" width="15" height="15"/>' +  '</td>' + '<td>'+objJson[i].id+'</td>'+ '<td>'+objJson[i].name+'</td>'+ '<td>'+objJson[i].dsc+'</td>'+'<td>'+objJson[i].colab_name+'</td>'+
                      '</tr>';
    } 

   tablaTarea += '</tbody>'+'</table>';



   return tablaTarea;                   
}
```

Necesitaría ejecutar esta linea al hacer lick sobre una fila del bucle for o sobre la imagen.

Es una tabla que almaceno en una variable.
Alguna idea? Gracias.

```
$('#formulario').load('php/formTarea.php?idTarea='+data_formTareaBt['id']);
```

Comment: probá usando `onclick` en la etiqueta de la imagen o la fila de la tabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas al modificar el DOM con js en este caso con un ajax que esta insertando una tabla que no existía cuando el js ha leido de primeras el DOM, entonces necesitas decirle al jquery que ese DOM ha cambiado, en el segundo parametro del ".on" le indicas el dom que es dinamico. Prueba con algo de esto :

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "table tr", function() {
  //tu codigo cuando se hace click sobre un tr
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Iba a decir en un comentario que @germanio tiene razón, pero dice que no puedo agregar comentarios. Tu pregunta está un poco confusa y desordenada. Si entiendo bien lo que necesitas es algo como:

```
'<tr onclick="funcion_a_ejecutar('+objJson[i].id+')">'+
                              '<td>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' ...
```

o

```
 '<td>'+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' +'<img src="img/flecha.png" width="15" height="15" onclick="funcion_a_ejecutar('+objJson[i].id+')"/>'...
```

Y una función:

```
function funcion_a_ejecutar(id){
    // reemplazando data_formTareaBt['id']) por el parámetro recibido id;
    $('#formulario').load('php/formTarea.php?idTarea='+id);
}
```

Ahora, supongo que la cosa no queda ahí, ya que esperas que se pueda ver como un link en el cual tu cursor se transforma a la mano. Para éso deberás aplicarle ya sea estilo en línea o mediante un CSS (a la línea o a la imagen) donde pongas

```
style="cursor:hand;"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda, me ha sido muy util, pido disculpas por la forma en la que he formulado la pregunta. Un saludo